# Position of last subfigure differs within a figure

Tags: tikz-pgf, subcaption

I want a number of graphs (in this example four) in one figure and try this with the following code:

```
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{figure}[h]
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
        \centering
    \definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{80,80,160}
    \definecolor{mygreen}{RGB}{80,160,80}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      [scale=.8,auto=left,every node/.style={circle,fill=blue!20}]
      \node (n7) at (8,8) {7};
      \node (n6) at (9,8) {6};
      \node (n5) at (10,8) {5};
      \node (n2) at (9,7) {2};
      \node (n3) at (10,7) {3};
      \node (n4) at (10,6) {4};
      \node (n1) at (6,6) {1};
      \node (n8) at (13,7) {8};

      \draw (n7) -- (n6);
      \draw (n6) -- (n5);
      \draw (n3) -- (n4);
      \draw (n7) -- (n2);
      \draw (n6) -- (n2);
      \draw (n5) -- (n2);
      \draw (n6) -- (n3);
      \draw (n5) -- (n3);
      \draw (n2) -- (n3);
      \draw (n2) -- (n4);

    \end{tikzpicture}
    \subcaption{Picture 1}
    \label{fig:1}
  \end{subfigure}
  %
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
        \centering
    \definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{80,80,160}
    \definecolor{mygreen}{RGB}{80,160,80}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      [scale=.8,auto=left,every node/.style={circle,fill=blue!20}]
      \node (n7) at (8,8) {7};
      \node (n6) at (9,8) {6};
      \node (n5) at (10,8) {5};
      \node (n2) at (9,7) {2};
      \node (n3) at (10,7) {3};
      \node (n4) at (10,6) {4};
      \node (n1) at (6,6) {1};
      \node (n8) at (13,7) {8};

      \draw (n7) -- (n6);
      \draw (n6) -- (n5);
      \draw (n3) -- (n4);
      \draw (n7) -- (n2);
      \draw (n6) -- (n2);
      \draw (n5) -- (n2);
      \draw (n6) -- (n3);
      \draw (n5) -- (n3);
      \draw (n2) -- (n3);
      \draw (n2) -- (n4);

    \end{tikzpicture}
    \subcaption{Picture 2}
    \label{fig:2}
  \end{subfigure}
%
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
        \centering
    \definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{80,80,160}
    \definecolor{mygreen}{RGB}{80,160,80}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      [scale=.8,auto=left,every node/.style={circle,fill=blue!20}]
      \node (n7) at (8,8) {7};
      \node (n6) at (9,8) {6};
      \node (n5) at (10,8) {5};
      \node (n2) at (9,7) {2};
      \node (n3) at (10,7) {3};
      \node (n4) at (10,6) {4};
      \node (n1) at (6,6) {1};
      \node (n8) at (13,7) {8};

      \draw (n7) -- (n6);
      \draw (n6) -- (n5);
      \draw (n3) -- (n4);
      \draw (n7) -- (n2);
      \draw (n6) -- (n2);
      \draw (n5) -- (n2);
      \draw (n6) -- (n3);
      \draw (n5) -- (n3);
      \draw (n2) -- (n3);
      \draw (n2) -- (n4);

    \end{tikzpicture}
    \subcaption{Picture 1}
    \label{fig:1}
  \end{subfigure}
%
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
        \centering
    \definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{80,80,160}
    \definecolor{mygreen}{RGB}{80,160,80}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      [scale=.8,auto=left,every node/.style={circle,fill=blue!20}]
      \node (n7) at (8,8) {7};
      \node (n6) at (9,8) {6};
      \node (n5) at (10,8) {5};
      \node (n2) at (9,7) {2};
      \node (n3) at (10,7) {3};
      \node (n4) at (10,6) {4};
      \node (n1) at (6,6) {1};
      \node (n8) at (13,7) {8};

      \draw (n7) -- (n6);
      \draw (n6) -- (n5);
      \draw (n3) -- (n4);
      \draw (n7) -- (n2);
      \draw (n6) -- (n2);
      \draw (n5) -- (n2);
      \draw (n6) -- (n3);
      \draw (n5) -- (n3);
      \draw (n2) -- (n3);
      \draw (n2) -- (n4);

    \end{tikzpicture}
    \subcaption{Picture 1}
    \label{fig:1}
  \end{subfigure}
  \caption{Pictures}
  \label{all sub assigns}
\end{figure}
```

This results in the following figure:
[image]

However, I want subfigure (d) in the corner right below, just like subfigure (b).
**My first question is how to achieve this.**

**My second question** is whether it is possible to include a frame around each subfigure, but not around the big figure itself.

**If someone has time left, my third question** is how position three or four subfigures in a way that the subfigures are still seperated properly.

Answers to any of these questions is really appreciated.

Comment: Please make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)

Comment: about the frame around each figure: add `\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}` to your document and `show background rectangle` to each `tikzpicture`. And please read section 43 background Library in [pgfmanual](http://texdoc.net/pkg/pgf#page=519).

Comment: The `%` between all subfigures makes that all of them form a unique line which is broken after the second one. Therefore the first line characters are expanded to fill the whole line, and the second line characters are not expanded. Like any other regular paragraph. As an alternative you can distribute the figures on a `tabular`.

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
        \centering
        \definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{80,80,160}
        \definecolor{mygreen}{RGB}{80,160,80}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        [scale=.8,auto=left,every node/.style={circle,fill=blue!20}]
        \node (n7) at (8,8) {7};
        \node (n6) at (9,8) {6};
        \node (n5) at (10,8) {5};
        \node (n2) at (9,7) {2};
        \node (n3) at (10,7) {3};
        \node (n4) at (10,6) {4};
        \node (n1) at (6,6) {1};
        \node (n8) at (13,7) {8};

        \draw (n7) -- (n6);
        \draw (n6) -- (n5);
        \draw (n3) -- (n4);
        \draw (n7) -- (n2);
        \draw (n6) -- (n2);
        \draw (n5) -- (n2);
        \draw (n6) -- (n3);
        \draw (n5) -- (n3);
        \draw (n2) -- (n3);
        \draw (n2) -- (n4);

        \end{tikzpicture}
        \subcaption{Picture 1}
        \label{fig:1}
    \end{subfigure}
    %
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
        \centering
        \definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{80,80,160}
        \definecolor{mygreen}{RGB}{80,160,80}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        [scale=.8,auto=left,every node/.style={circle,fill=blue!20}]
        \node (n7) at (8,8) {7};
        \node (n6) at (9,8) {6};
        \node (n5) at (10,8) {5};
        \node (n2) at (9,7) {2};
        \node (n3) at (10,7) {3};
        \node (n4) at (10,6) {4};
        \node (n1) at (6,6) {1};
        \node (n8) at (13,7) {8};

        \draw (n7) -- (n6);
        \draw (n6) -- (n5);
        \draw (n3) -- (n4);
        \draw (n7) -- (n2);
        \draw (n6) -- (n2);
        \draw (n5) -- (n2);
        \draw (n6) -- (n3);
        \draw (n5) -- (n3);
        \draw (n2) -- (n3);
        \draw (n2) -- (n4);

        \end{tikzpicture}
        \subcaption{Picture 2}
        \label{fig:2}
    \end{subfigure}

    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
        \centering
        \definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{80,80,160}
        \definecolor{mygreen}{RGB}{80,160,80}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        [scale=.8,auto=left,every node/.style={circle,fill=blue!20}]
        \node (n7) at (8,8) {7};
        \node (n6) at (9,8) {6};
        \node (n5) at (10,8) {5};
        \node (n2) at (9,7) {2};
        \node (n3) at (10,7) {3};
        \node (n4) at (10,6) {4};
        \node (n1) at (6,6) {1};
        \node (n8) at (13,7) {8};

        \draw (n7) -- (n6);
        \draw (n6) -- (n5);
        \draw (n3) -- (n4);
        \draw (n7) -- (n2);
        \draw (n6) -- (n2);
        \draw (n5) -- (n2);
        \draw (n6) -- (n3);
        \draw (n5) -- (n3);
        \draw (n2) -- (n3);
        \draw (n2) -- (n4);

        \end{tikzpicture}
        \subcaption{Picture 1}
        \label{fig:1}
    \end{subfigure}
%
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
        \centering
        \definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{80,80,160}
        \definecolor{mygreen}{RGB}{80,160,80}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        [scale=.8,auto=left,every node/.style={circle,fill=blue!20}]
        \node (n7) at (8,8) {7};
        \node (n6) at (9,8) {6};
        \node (n5) at (10,8) {5};
        \node (n2) at (9,7) {2};
        \node (n3) at (10,7) {3};
        \node (n4) at (10,6) {4};
        \node (n1) at (6,6) {1};
        \node (n8) at (13,7) {8};

        \draw (n7) -- (n6);
        \draw (n6) -- (n5);
        \draw (n3) -- (n4);
        \draw (n7) -- (n2);
        \draw (n6) -- (n2);
        \draw (n5) -- (n2);
        \draw (n6) -- (n3);
        \draw (n5) -- (n3);
        \draw (n2) -- (n3);
        \draw (n2) -- (n4);

        \end{tikzpicture}
        \subcaption{Picture 1}
        \label{fig:1}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{Pictures}
    \label{all sub assigns}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

All four in a row (also with a frame here):

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\makebox[\linewidth]{%
    \fbox{\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
     ...
      \end{subfigure}%
    }% end \fbox
    \fbox{...
    ...
    \% end \fbox
 }% end \makebox
\end{figure}
```

[image]

Comment: This approach doesn't assure that the contents of the `figure` environment fit inside the width of the text block.

Comment: Did I said something different??? ...  It is only an example how more than \textwidth can be used to get something in a row!

Comment: I certainly did not claim that you made any such claim; I was merely pointing out a potential issue. Since you didn't provide a lot of text to accompany the code and screenshot, readers might be left wondering what the code achieves -- and what it does not.

Answer (score 2):

When creating figures with TikZ, the easiest way is to position them using all the power of Tikz. To do this, simply place them each in a `scope` *(see page 126 of 3.0.1a manual)*. 
To frame them, we name this `scope`, with the `local bounding box` key (see page 1033 of the manual) and we place the `caption` text and the `frame` using this `scope`.

The advantage is that all these placements are relative: by moving the `scopes`, the `caption` text and the `frame` are correctly positioned in the desired place.

**Not** knowing if you want the caption text `Picture 1`, `Picture 2`, `Picture 3` to be **inside** the frame or **outside**, I have put ex illustration the two possibilities.

[image: capture]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}

\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{80,80,160}
\definecolor{mygreen}{RGB}{80,160,80}
\begin{tikzpicture}
[scale=.8,auto=left,every node/.style={circle,fill=blue!20}]
\begin{scope}[local bounding box= upleft]
\node (n7) at (8,8) {7};
\node (n6) at (9,8) {6};
\node (n5) at (10,8) {5};
\node (n2) at (9,7) {2};
\node (n3) at (10,7) {3};
\node (n4) at (10,6) {4};
\node (n1) at (6,6) {1};
\node (n8) at (13,7) {8};

\draw (n7) -- (n6);
\draw (n6) -- (n5);
\draw (n3) -- (n4);
\draw (n7) -- (n2);
\draw (n6) -- (n2);
\draw (n5) -- (n2);
\draw (n6) -- (n3);
\draw (n5) -- (n3);
\draw (n2) -- (n3);
\draw (n2) -- (n4);
\node[below=3mm of upleft,rectangle, fill=none]{Picture 1};
\end{scope}

\draw([shift={(-.2,-.2)}]upleft.south west)rectangle([shift={(.2,.2)}]upleft.north east);


\begin{scope}[shift={(9,0)},local bounding box= upright]
\node (n7) at (8,8) {7};
\node (n6) at (9,8) {6};
\node (n5) at (10,8) {5};
\node (n2) at (9,7) {2};
\node (n3) at (10,7) {3};
\node (n4) at (10,6) {4};
\node (n1) at (6,6) {1};
\node (n8) at (13,7) {8};

\draw (n7) -- (n6);
\draw (n6) -- (n5);
\draw (n3) -- (n4);
\draw (n7) -- (n2);
\draw (n6) -- (n2);
\draw (n5) -- (n2);
\draw (n6) -- (n3);
\draw (n5) -- (n3);
\draw (n2) -- (n3);
\draw (n2) -- (n4);
\node[below=3mm of upright,rectangle, fill=none]{Picture 2};
\end{scope}
\draw([shift={(-.2,-.2)}]upright.south west)rectangle([shift={(.2,.2)}]upright.north east);


\begin{scope}[shift={(0,-5)},local bounding box= downleft]
\node (n7) at (8,8) {7};
\node (n6) at (9,8) {6};
\node (n5) at (10,8) {5};
\node (n2) at (9,7) {2};
\node (n3) at (10,7) {3};
\node (n4) at (10,6) {4};
\node (n1) at (6,6) {1};
\node (n8) at (13,7) {8};

\draw (n7) -- (n6);
\draw (n6) -- (n5);
\draw (n3) -- (n4);
\draw (n7) -- (n2);
\draw (n6) -- (n2);
\draw (n5) -- (n2);
\draw (n6) -- (n3);
\draw (n5) -- (n3);
\draw (n2) -- (n3);
\draw (n2) -- (n4);
\end{scope}
\node[below=3mm of downleft,rectangle, fill=none]{Picture 3};
\draw([shift={(-.2,-.2)}]downleft.south west)rectangle([shift={(.2,.2)}]downleft.north east);

\begin{scope}[shift={(9,-5)},local bounding box= downright]
\node (n7) at (8,8) {7};
\node (n6) at (9,8) {6};
\node (n5) at (10,8) {5};
\node (n2) at (9,7) {2};
\node (n3) at (10,7) {3};
\node (n4) at (10,6) {4};
\node (n1) at (6,6) {1};
\node (n8) at (13,7) {8};

\draw (n7) -- (n6);
\draw (n6) -- (n5);
\draw (n3) -- (n4);
\draw (n7) -- (n2);
\draw (n6) -- (n2);
\draw (n5) -- (n2);
\draw (n6) -- (n3);
\draw (n5) -- (n3);
\draw (n2) -- (n3);
\draw (n2) -- (n4);
\end{scope}
\node[below=3mm of downright,rectangle, fill=none]{Picture 4};
\draw([shift={(-.2,-.2)}]downright.south west)rectangle([shift={(.2,.2)}]downright.north east);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Translated with www.DeepL.com/Translator

Answer (score 0):

The contents of the 4 `subfigure` environments are all wider than `0.4\textwidth`. Do note that specifying a width of a `subfigure` environment does *not* imply that its contents will fit inside the specified width.

I suggest you (a) make the `subfigure` environments a bit wider (`0.45\textwidth`, say), (b) replace `\centering` with `\raggedright and`\raggedleft`, respectively, and (c) maximize the horizontal separation between the subfigures via`\hfill` instructions.

The framelines in the following screenshot are generated by loading the `geometry` package with the option `showframe`. For the final version of your real document, be sure to omit the `showframe` option.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{subcaption,tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
    \raggedright
    \definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{80,80,160}
    \definecolor{mygreen}{RGB}{80,160,80}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      [scale=.8,auto=left,every node/.style={circle,fill=blue!20}]
      \node (n7) at (8,8) {7};
      \node (n6) at (9,8) {6};
      \node (n5) at (10,8) {5};
      \node (n2) at (9,7) {2};
      \node (n3) at (10,7) {3};
      \node (n4) at (10,6) {4};
      \node (n1) at (6,6) {1};
      \node (n8) at (13,7) {8};

      \draw (n7) -- (n6);
      \draw (n6) -- (n5);
      \draw (n3) -- (n4);
      \draw (n7) -- (n2);
      \draw (n6) -- (n2);
      \draw (n5) -- (n2);
      \draw (n6) -- (n3);
      \draw (n5) -- (n3);
      \draw (n2) -- (n3);
      \draw (n2) -- (n4);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \subcaption{Picture 1}
    \label{fig:1}
  \end{subfigure}%
  \hfill
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
    \raggedleft
    \definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{80,80,160}
    \definecolor{mygreen}{RGB}{80,160,80}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      [scale=.8,auto=left,every node/.style={circle,fill=blue!20}]
      \node (n7) at (8,8) {7};
      \node (n6) at (9,8) {6};
      \node (n5) at (10,8) {5};
      \node (n2) at (9,7) {2};
      \node (n3) at (10,7) {3};
      \node (n4) at (10,6) {4};
      \node (n1) at (6,6) {1};
      \node (n8) at (13,7) {8};

      \draw (n7) -- (n6);
      \draw (n6) -- (n5);
      \draw (n3) -- (n4);
      \draw (n7) -- (n2);
      \draw (n6) -- (n2);
      \draw (n5) -- (n2);
      \draw (n6) -- (n3);
      \draw (n5) -- (n3);
      \draw (n2) -- (n3);
      \draw (n2) -- (n4);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \subcaption{Picture 2}
    \label{fig:2}
  \end{subfigure}

  \bigskip

  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
    \raggedright
    \definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{80,80,160}
    \definecolor{mygreen}{RGB}{80,160,80}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      [scale=.8,auto=left,every node/.style={circle,fill=blue!20}]
      \node (n7) at (8,8) {7};
      \node (n6) at (9,8) {6};
      \node (n5) at (10,8) {5};
      \node (n2) at (9,7) {2};
      \node (n3) at (10,7) {3};
      \node (n4) at (10,6) {4};
      \node (n1) at (6,6) {1};
      \node (n8) at (13,7) {8};

      \draw (n7) -- (n6);
      \draw (n6) -- (n5);
      \draw (n3) -- (n4);
      \draw (n7) -- (n2);
      \draw (n6) -- (n2);
      \draw (n5) -- (n2);
      \draw (n6) -- (n3);
      \draw (n5) -- (n3);
      \draw (n2) -- (n3);
      \draw (n2) -- (n4);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \subcaption{Picture 3}
    \label{fig:3}
  \end{subfigure}%
  \hfill
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
    \raggedleft
    \definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{80,80,160}
    \definecolor{mygreen}{RGB}{80,160,80}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      [scale=.8,auto=left,every node/.style={circle,fill=blue!20}]
      \node (n7) at (8,8) {7};
      \node (n6) at (9,8) {6};
      \node (n5) at (10,8) {5};
      \node (n2) at (9,7) {2};
      \node (n3) at (10,7) {3};
      \node (n4) at (10,6) {4};
      \node (n1) at (6,6) {1};
      \node (n8) at (13,7) {8};

      \draw (n7) -- (n6);
      \draw (n6) -- (n5);
      \draw (n3) -- (n4);
      \draw (n7) -- (n2);
      \draw (n6) -- (n2);
      \draw (n5) -- (n2);
      \draw (n6) -- (n3);
      \draw (n5) -- (n3);
      \draw (n2) -- (n3);
      \draw (n2) -- (n4);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \subcaption{Picture 4}
    \label{fig:4}
  \end{subfigure}
\caption{Pictures}
\label{all sub assigns}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: BTW, if you need to omit the fourth subfigure, just omit (or comment out) its code.